# Firefox opens and quits without an error message

Tags: firefox

Firefox opens and quits without an error message. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try starting firefox from a terminal window

Comment: ^ and [edit] your question to show the output. However, I've noticed that recent versions of firefox disown themselves from the shell and don't print anything, which is nice and tidy, but annoying for debugging. If anyone knows how to get it to print useful things (beyond using the `-jsconsole` option, which often isn't very illuminating in my experience), please add them here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening Firefox in Safe Mode from a Terminal:

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-wont-start-find-solutions

Comment: did that fix your problem? Do you have to use safe mode every time?

Comment: Yes- after starting in safe mode, I was able to quit and open Firefox normally, and have had no problems since.